# Why does a UV Map cover the entire model?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image

Briefly, I have done extensive research with tutorials etc regarding a problem I am experiencing and it is my hope that perhaps someone could allow some insight!
I am successfully utilizing projection painting of an image to a model's head, however, upon exporting the model and observing through a web page the uv map covers the entire model rather than just the head area. which has remained the selected in edit mode. The uv map only suggests the head area which is continually repeated over the entire model even after attempting to deselect "Repeat" in image mapping which I changed to "Clip".

Comment: At least in blender, all vertices of your mesh must be unwrapped. Not how the exporters/formats handle this, but it would be helpful to know what format you are exporting to.

Comment: I am exporting to three.js as the usual json obj. I was suspecting that I may need to unwrap the entire model. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the vertices you would like to ignore off the UV Map ... to some side.  Use this in combination with Clip.